# PHP to local printer

Tags: php

I'm creating a formatted list of data from a MySQL database table and 'echoing' it to screen perfectly well.  How do I instead send the output to a local default printer, with or without a printer popup?
There must be a simple answer to this but I can't find it anywhere.  Any help much appreciated.
Bob

I've looked all over and can't find anything other than saving it as a file with fopen() and fwrite(). And that of course needs the user to choose a path to save it in and a separate print procedure.  I just want the php script to send the output to the printer.

Comment: If it's on a client machine, then how would you know what printer to send it to.  Being able to print directly to a users machine isn't something you could normally do (AFAIK) and would be quite annoying if any website could print on your local machine.

Comment: You haven't really explained the setup you have, but in general: PHP can only send data to printers that are connected to the server, not the client. To trigger printing in the client (like a browser), all you can do is tell the client to print (using JS), but then it's up to the client to handle the rest (like showing the print-popup or not.) That's not something you can decide for them since it's not a part of your application, but the client application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe use something like https://tcpdf.org/about/

It creates and display a PDF which almost all devices with a browser can print and even save.

Comment: Looks like this is the only way my client can get a print of the results generated by the script.  Many thanks.

Comment: What would creating a PDF solve? This would still give them a print-dialog popup when they try and print the PDF. If that is OK, then I don't see any reason to overcomplicate it by creating a PDF over outputting it directly in the browser and print from there? And most OS's also have a "Save as PDF" option in the print-dialog, which would allow them to save it as PDF instead, if they wanted to (without any extra work from you)